# ACF page while loop breaks footer while loop

Tags: php, loop, advanced-custom-fields, html

So basically i have a main page and a footer page. Both are seperate .php files.

Im using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/) for this site.

Following the documentation, ive created a while loop for my 'flexible content' in the main page and it works, displaying all the data that gets looped and hooked from the CMS input fields.

My Problem is in the footer, i have a while loop that displays links, but it wont display **unless** i remove the while loop from the main page, then the links display in the footer.

I honnestly dot get why this happens ive tested allot and get my head wrapped around this, please help.

**Main page code:**

```
<?php

// check if the flexible content field has rows of data
if( have_rows('flexible_content_field_name') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('flexible_content_field_name') ) : the_row();

        // check current row layout
        if( get_row_layout() == 'gallery' ):

            // check if the nested repeater field has rows of data
            if( have_rows('images') ):

                echo '<ul>';

                // loop through the rows of data
                while ( have_rows('images') ) : the_row();

                    $image = get_sub_field('image');

                    echo '<li><img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" /></li>';

                endwhile;

                echo '</ul>';

            endif;

        endif;

    endwhile;

else :

    // no layouts found

endif;

?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Footer Code:**

```
<div class="links">

         <?php

            if( have_rows('footer_page_links', 'option') ): 
            var_dump("test");
            while( have_rows('footer_page_links', 'option') ): the_row();

            ?>

            <p><a href="<?php the_sub_field('footer_link');   ?>"><?php the_sub_field('footer_link_name'); ?></a></p>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>   


</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

I would just like to add , not even the `vardump()` displays in the footer if main page while loop is implemented so it never gets inside the footer loop. The footer uses ACF option page - > [LINK](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/)

Also all other option fields in footer displays, if its not within the while loop. I have removed the main page while loop then the footer while loop works, and this only happens with flexible content, my other pages with loops, that does non consists of flexible content works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add `'option'` to your footer `the_sub_field()` calls:

`<p><a href="<?php the_sub_field('footer_link', 'option');   ?>"><?php the_sub_field('footer_link_name', 'option'); ?></a></p>`

`var_dump()` is used to dump a variable, not a string, so you would need to do something like `var_dump($test)` for that line to work. You are probably getting errors and warnings in your PHP log files - if not, you could turn on WP Debug to help figure out which lines of code are causing issues.

Comment: Hi Thanks for help, so if you look at docs from ACF, you dont need `'option'` for the sub-fields, also adding it does not resolve issue. The `vardump` i added a string just to see if it enters the `if` , on the other pages my `vardump` string shows up. Then for the WP Debug thanks for that i have tried it and for the pages i dont see the links in the footer it shows no errors, which makes me think this is an ACF bug?